# Update customer records

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-identity

In my app I have an update action to update the customers records in the back-end.
Further, as I know it's supposed to save any updates or non (null) when one field wasn't changed.
However, when I try to click save I'm getting a sql error, that the "MobileNumber" was not supplied.

Here is my data tier class:

```
 #region Update rider's info
        public bool updateRiders(RidersModel rider)
        {


            query = "UPDATE Users SET firstName = @firstName," +
                    " lastName = @lastName, email = @email, Address = @Address," +
                    " MobileNumber = @MobileNumber, city = @city," +
                    "state = @state, zipCode = @zipCode, UserName =@UserName, users_Id = @users_Id  " +
                    "WHERE usersId = @ID;";

            conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
            cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

            cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rider.usersId;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.firstName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.lastName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.email;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.Address;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.city;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.state;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@zipCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rider.zipCode;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@MobileNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = rider.mobileNumber;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256).Value = rider.UserName;
            cmd.Parameters.Add("@users_Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = rider.userID;


            try
            {
                conn.Open();
                rows = cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
                if (rows > 0)
                {
                    success = true;
                }

            }
            catch (SqlException ex)
            {

                throw new Exception(ex.Message);

            }
            finally
            {
                conn.Close();
            }

            return success;

        }
```

my Action is as the following :

```
 [HttpGet]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EditRiders(int id)
        {
            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new RidesDbContext()));

            IdentityUser theUser = new IdentityUser();
            theUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

            RidersModel rider = new RidersModel();
            RidersTier tier = new RidersTier();
            rider.email = theUser.UserName;
            rider.email = theUser.Email;
            rider.mobileNumber = theUser.PhoneNumber;
            rider.Password = theUser.PasswordHash;
            rider.userID = theUser.Id;



            rider = tier.getRidersById(id);



            return View(rider);
        }


        [HttpPost]
        public async Task<ActionResult> EditRiders(RidersModel rider)
        {

            var userStore = new UserStore<IdentityUser>();
            var userManager = new UserManager<IdentityUser>(new UserStore<IdentityUser>(new RidesDbContext()));

            IdentityUser theUser = new IdentityUser();



            if (ModelState.IsValid)
            {
                theUser = await userManager.FindByIdAsync(User.Identity.GetUserId());

                rider.email = theUser.UserName;
                rider.email = theUser.Email;
                rider.mobileNumber = theUser.PhoneNumber;
                rider.Password = theUser.PasswordHash;
                rider.userID = theUser.Id;

                RidersTier tier = new RidersTier();
                tier.updateRiders(rider);
            }



            TempData["ad"] = "User info has been updated";

            return View(rider);
        }
```

Is there any reason for that?

I would appreciate your help. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think you have to provide the parameter variables in the order that they appear in the sql statement. I think the `@ID` is fine since that's in the `where` clause, but I'm not sure. Give this a try, if this doesn't work then put the `@ID` parameter last:

```
query = @"
    UPDATE Users 
    SET 
        firstName = @firstName,
        lastName = @lastName, 
        email = @email, 
        Address = @Address,
        MobileNumber = @MobileNumber, 
        city = @city,
        state = @state, 
        zipCode = @zipCode, 
        UserName = @UserName, 
        users_Id = @users_Id  
    WHERE usersId = @ID;
";

conn = new SqlConnection(connectionString);
cmd = new SqlCommand(query, conn);

cmd.Parameters.Add("@ID", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rider.usersId;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@firstName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.firstName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@lastName", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.lastName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@email", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.email;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@Address", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.Address;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@MobileNumber", SqlDbType.VarChar, 200).Value = rider.mobileNumber;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@city", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.city;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@state", SqlDbType.VarChar, 255).Value = rider.state;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@zipCode", SqlDbType.Int).Value = rider.zipCode;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@UserName", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 256).Value = rider.UserName;
cmd.Parameters.Add("@users_Id", SqlDbType.NVarChar, 128).Value = rider.userID;
```

Comment: I don't think this is an issue, I tried though but it didn't work

Comment: yea that's right, I just replicated this issue but was only able to get the "...'@MobileNumber', which was not supplied" exception when I deliberately set `rider.mobileNumber = null` so that value must evaluate to null when this sql statement is being executed. I would check the code for the method `FindByIdAsync`.